# Python got no result and KeyError:1

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def fre(dic, k):
    max_k = dic.keys()[0]
    max_v = dic.values()[0]
    while len(dic2) < k:
        for key, value in dic.items():
            if max_v < value:
                max_k = key
                max_v = value

        dic2[max_k] = max_v
        del dic[max_k]
    return dic2
# dic is a dictionary, k is an int
```

This question is to get the k biggest value in dic and get the matched key :value pairs. But I got running problem and got KeyError: 1.

Comment: After you `del dic[max_k]`, in the next iteration of the `while` loop, `max_k` starts with the same value, you don't find any other better key in your dictionary, and then you try and delete it again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
This problem probably involves the values in the dictionary you passed in -- which you failed to include in your posting.  Also give us the full error message.

Comment: You should *always* post the entire traceback and error message when asking questions about exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, each time through the loop, you leave `max_k` and `max_v` to the key-value pair you just found.

Since that was the maximum value, no other value in the dictionary will be larger. So at the end of the loop, you'll still have the same `max_k` and `max_v`. And then you'll try to `del dic[max_k]` again, and it raises a `KeyError`, because you already deleted it.

The solution is simple: take the code that sets `max_k` and `max_v` to the first element, and move it into the outer loop, so it runs every time instead of just the first time:

```
while len(dic2) < k:
    max_k = dic.keys()[0]
    max_v = dic.values()[0]

    for key, value in dic.items():
        if max_v < value:
            max_k = key
            max_v = value

    dic2[max_k] = max_v
    del dic[max_k]
```

---

But, while we're at it, there are easier (or at least harder-to-get-subtly-wrong) ways to do this.

The most obvious is to just [sort the items by value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), then take the first `k`:

```
import operator

def fre(dic, k):
    return dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:k])
```

For more on how key functions work, and that `itemgetter`, see the [Sorting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

But you can make this more efficient. `sorted` obviously has to sort all `n` values, just to get the top `k`, so it takes `O(n)` space and `O(n log n)` time. If `k` is a lot smaller than `n`, you can do a lot better by using [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), which takes only `O(k)` space and `O(n log k)` time:

```
import heapq
import operator

def fre(dic, k):
    return dict(heapq.nlargest(k, dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Either way, this doesn't delete the keys from `dic`; if you need that, you can do that manually:

```
def fre(dic, k):
    dic2 = dict(heapq.nlargest(k, dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
    for key in dic2:
        del dic[key]
    return dic2
```